# Why does CVS still show ignored folders as unversioned files in PHPStorm?

Tags: cvs, phpstorm, ignore

Assuming this structure:

```
assets/
    .sass-cache/
      somerandomfoldername/
        somerandomfilename.scssc
      someotherrandomfoldername/
        someorandomfilenam.pngc
     css/
       master.css
     scss/
       master.scss
.cvsignore
```

The `.cvsignore` contains

```
.sass-cache
```

It seems to be working as all the files within this folders are ignored. But all the folders themselves are not. Is this a "feature" of CVS, a PHPStorm bug or am I missing something?

Comment: That´s probably a PHPStorm "feature" as CVS does not operate on folders but on files directly. Maybe the IDE just want to keep you informed there are folders not under version control?

Comment: Most likely - it's quite irritating nevertheless.